# Message Collapsing

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm trying to determine if there's a way for Azure Service Bus to provide message collapsing. Specifically I'm after something like:

1. First event into a queue gets picked up straight away
2. All other events that are queued within the next N seconds, and match some criteria (e.g. matching message ids), have the schedule enqueue set to a value so they fire at the end of the N seconds. If a "waiting" message already exists it should be deleted.
3. After the N seconds has expired the newest scheduled message appears and is picked up.

Basically I need a way to get a good time-to-first-event, but provide protection from over processing events from chatty sources.

Does anyone have a pattern they've used to get something close to these semantics?

**Update 1**

The messages involved aren't true duplicates, rather they're the current state of an entity that is used for some processing (e.g. a message that's generated each time a file is updated). The result of the processing of an early message is fully replaced by that of later messages (e.g. the result is the size of the file). So we still need to guarantee we process the most recent message, but it's a waste to process all M within N seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about [Duplicate Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection), especially in regards to matching MessageIds. If you want to evaluate some other attribute in the message for duplicate detection, maybe it's worth taking a step back and asking *Why are my publishers sending so many duplicate messages?* If it's unavoidable, maybe you can segregate your chatty consumers into a separate consumer group and manually handle the the duplicate check, then re-enqueue (just thinking out loud).

Comment: I updated the question to elaborate on the messages themselves. In this scenario they aren't true duplicates and so the existing duplicate detection doesn't work. If, however, the duplicate detection would keep the latest one and make it available once the detection window has elasped that would work.

Comment: @Brad, I can't find anything out of the box w/ Service Bus or Kafka that would do what you're looking for. My next idea would be to do the reducing on the consumer side by grouping my producer and taking the most recent message from a batch of messages (e.g. messages.GroupBy(m => m.Id).OrderBy(m => m.UpdateTime).Take(1)).